# Hard Definite integral inequality involving logarithms and polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Prove that if $f(x) = lnx$ ,

### $\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{f(xe^{x+1})dx}{(x+1)^2\ +\ f^2(x^x)} > \frac{\pi}{4}$

**My attempt** : I simplified the integrand and got the below integral.

### $\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{(lnx\ +\ x\ +\ 1)dx}{(x+1)^2\ +\ x^2(lnx)^2}$

After this, I thought of applying inequalities to compare this integral with the integral $\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{2}{x((lnx)^2+4)}dx$ which is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
But I do not know how to compare these integrals.

Also, please let me know if there are any other methods of proving this inequality.

(Please provide a solution which does not require the use of a graphing calculator / website)